# Json encode vs string array

Tags: php, json

I'm using the json_encode function to transform a php array to a json.
Now, i want to generate something like this :

```
"Strings": ["String 1","String 2","String 3"]
```

I don't know how to do ?

I tried :

```
$array["strings"] = '["String 1","String 2","String 3"]';
```

But it doesn't work as i get this as result :

```
"Strings":"[\"String 1\", \"String 2\", \"String 3\"]"
```

Then i tried this

```
$array["strings"] = '[String 1,String 2,String 3]';
```

It doesn't work, i got this as result :

```
"Strings":"[String 1, String 2, String 3]"
```

Can someone help me please ?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json_encode( array( "strings"=>array("string1", "string2", "string3" ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define it like this

```
$array["String"] = ["String 1","String 2","String 3"];
```

then you output will be:

```
"String":["String 1","String 2","String 3"]
```